# Android some of the view elements not visible

Tags: android

I am creating a layout as below but the checkbox element is not visible on the scren where am i goign wrong ?

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seek" 
            android:layout_width="300dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:progress="50"/>

        ...and a few more elements here.

    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:text="somestring" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LinearLayout` before the `CheckBox` has its height set to `MATCH_PARENT`(and it fills all the parent's height) and the parent `LinearLayout` of both has the orientation set to vertical so the `CheckBox` is pushed out of the screen.

Set the height of the `LinearLayout` containing the `SeekBar` to `WRAP_CONTENT` for example.

Answer (score 0):

change your LinerLayout definition it cannot be android:layout_height="match_parent"

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

if you set match_parent for linearlayout it consumes all content so wrap_content is better.
But if you set it as I wrote checkbox will be at bottom page a linearlayout will consumes remaing part of screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your inner Linear Layout's height and width to wrap content.
Try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seek"
            android:layout_width="300dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="50" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="somestring" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="50" />
</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="somestring" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout chose one element that you want to be flexible in size, say height wise. Then make its `height="0dp"` and `weight="1"`.  Make heights of rest of elements: `height="wrap_content"`.

Also you may have given discreet size of some dp to your other elements, and hence their total height runs out of available screen space OR there are too many elements that they go beyond your screen height. In this case, wrap your layout in a `ScrollView`.